# Knockout validation of checkbox not showing message

Tags: knockout-validation

I have this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/63qJe/3/ that works, but does not show the validation method.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: approveTerms"/>
<label for="algvw">Yes, I agree to the general terms and conditions</label>
<span data-bind="validationMessage: approveTerms"></span>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: stepForward">Commit order</button>
```

JS:

```
ko.validation.rules['checkedTerms'] = {
    validator: function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        if (!value)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};
function ovm() {
    var self = this;
    self.approveTerms = ko.observable(false).extend({
        checkedTerms: { message: 'Approval required' }
    });
    self.currentStep = ko.observable(1);
    self.stepForward = function () {
        if (self.currentStep() === 1)
            commitOrder(self);
    };
}
window.vm = new ovm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

function commitOrder(vm) {
    if (vm.approveTerms())
        alert("GO!");
    else
        alert("Nooooooooo");
}
```

I am rather new to KO and still learning. I have other validators on textfields and those work, but this checkbox is causing me a headache.

why can't I just do this:

```
self.approveTerms = ko.observable(false).extend({ required: true, message:'approval req.' });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a [custom validator rule](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules) you need to call

```
 ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

after your custom rules in order to the validation plugin registers the new validators.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74a85/).

Or if you only want to check for that your checkbox is checked you can use the [built in](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules) `equal` validator:

```
self.approveTerms = ko.observable(false).extend(
    { equal: { params: true, message:'approval req.' }});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLuUf/).

Comment: Hi nemesv, when I check the second jsfiddle link and hit the submit button it does not display the message.

Comment: @JPHellemons In which browser? It works fine for me in the latest Chrome, both the "Go" and "Nooooooooo" message are displayed fine in both JSFiddle...

Comment: I have ff24 and if i hit the submit button it says no, but does not display the validationmessage. I first have to select and deselect the checkbox before the message shows. and somehow chrome28 says in the console, failed to load resources.

Comment: Displaying the validation message on submit is not working in any of the three fiddles here in the answers. For display the error message without check and recheck the chekbox you need to write some additional code... but you are better with asking this in a new question.

Comment: To get started you should have a look how ko.validatedObservables are working in the validation plugin's documentation.

Comment: Ok, but this question was about showing the validation error on submit if it is not checked. sorry for being unclear

Comment: There are multile solution like: simply calling `vm.approveTerms.notifySubscribers();` which triggers the message showing http://jsfiddle.net/bgYZr/. Or using a [validation group](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables) and calling  `vm.errors.showAllMessages();` http://jsfiddle.net/tBET8/

Answer (score 1):

Try Custom validator instead

```
var checkedTerms = function (value) {
        alert(value);
        console.log(value);
        if (!value) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

function ovm() {
    var self = this;
    self.approveTerms = ko.observable(false).extend({
        validation: { validator:checkedTerms, message: 'Approval required' }
    });
    self.currentStep = ko.observable(1);
    self.stepForward = function () {
        if (self.currentStep() === 1)
            commitOrder(self);
    };
}
```

Here is working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/63qJe/5/